# How to get value of ul li made dropdown using php in URL by get method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a form with multiple dropdown (by ul li) and after selecting drop down items i have to search the results by clicking search button to search page.

I am passing the selected data to other search page by get method but it does not passes correctly in URL.

**My code for dropdown:-**

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" />
    <ul class="list" name="location">
        <li value="DELHI">DELHI</li>
        <li value="MUMBAI">MUMBAI</li>
        <li value="HYDERABAD">HYDERABAD</li>
    </ul>


     <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" />
    <ul class="list" name="type">
        <li value="HOUSE">HOUSE</li>
        <li value="FLAT">FLAT</li>
        <li value="APPARTMENT">APPARTMENT</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Jquery Code:-**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.list li').click(function(e){
    var location = $(this).attr("value");
    $("input[name='location']").val(location);


     var type = $(this).attr("value");
     $("input[name='type']").val(type);

});
</script>
```

**search.php**

```
echo $location = $_GET['location'];
echo $type = $_GET['type'];
```

Comment: Show your full form code, One issue I can say on your existing code is that, when you select any li element this will set the value of both hidden field

Comment: Few questions.. Can you edit this to include the full `<form action="...` part of your code? By the looks of your jquery code, whenever either a type or location is selected, it sets both hidden inputs to the selected value (ie: select FLAT, then type=FLAT and location=FLAT), it seems like you also want two `click` functions for this one for each hidden input, I can post this in the solution if you need it too?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Yes that is the only issue so how can solve it?

Comment: @simandsim i edit my code with `<form> Tag` , Yes  either a type or location is selected, it sets both hidden inputs to the selected value , if you Know ths solution please post your answer, please.

Comment: @KUMAR one possible answer is given below, have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There are different ways to fix that** but one way to do it this way,

```js
$('.list li').click(function(e) {
  var clicked_element_value = $(this).attr("value");
  var parent = $(this).parent().attr('name');
  $("#" + parent).val(clicked_element_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="location" name="location" />
  <ul class="list" name="location">
   <li value="DELHI">DELHI</li>
   <li value="MUMBAI">MUMBAI</li>
   <li value="HYDERABAD">HYDERABAD</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" />
  <ul class="list" name="type">
   <li value="HOUSE">HOUSE</li>
   <li value="FLAT">FLAT</li>
   <li value="APPARTMENT">APPARTMENT</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="hidden" id="zip" name="zip" />
  <ul class="list" name="zip">
   <li value="121">121</li>
   <li value="456">456</li>
   <li value="789">789</li>
  </ul>

  <input type="hidden" id="post" name="post" />
  <ul class="list" name="post">
   <li value="9000">9000</li>
   <li value="9000">8000</li>
   <li value="7000">7000</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: but sir i have 4 dropdown in the ul li style?

Comment: @KUMAR glad it helps you some how :)